# How to use pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN?

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent, mouse

My simple question is how can I use pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN on a sprite or item to trigger an event?

e.g. I have item_A and want music to start when I press the object with my mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html.

Where `buttons` is your sprite group, which have [`Rect()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)s. You can define a `click()` function, for different sounds on each button.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():    
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
        x, y = event.pos
        for button in buttons:
            if button.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                print("play sound here.")

                # or, if button handles on clicking, by a defined function:
                button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

use events in your main loop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
        play_music()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to poll for events in your main loop, and when you detect a MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event you will need to check if it's on the sprite you want, and if it is then start the music.